# I cannot init a new World with box2D on Android

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

I added the gdx.jar and gdx-backend-android.jar in the Libraries tab. I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: newWorld` for

```
gravity = new Vector2(0,10f);        
world = new  World(gravity, false);
```

All the issues in google source code tracker cannot help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add these libraries to your app's build path?

Answer (score 4):

You only use the box2d wrapper i assume. In that case you have to load the natives yourself via System.load("gdx").

Comment: then you are still missing the libgdx.so files in the libs folder of your Android project. Why not just use libgdx directly and spare yourself the trouble?